# create simple timer android

Tags: java, android, timer

I want to make a simple timer to time how long it takes the user to do something in my app. What I have in mind is to simply start a timer, stop the timer and then display the time. I have been searching and haven't found a definitive solution that just works. Is it as simple as I envision or is this more complicated as I have found from searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How precise does the timer need to be?

The simplest way would be to take the time before performing the task and subtract it from the time after performing the task:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
// do some task
long timeTakenMs = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

If you mean a user-event-driven timer, you can apply the same principles as above:

```
// Declare instance variable
long start = 0L;

// OnStartTimer
start = System.currentTimeMillis();

// OnStopTimer
long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

Comment: ok that worked but how do you get it formatted properly? this is what I tried `time=System.currentTimeMillis() - seconds;
                        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
                        String dateString = fmt.format(time);` and it isnt't being displayed properly. it shows 18:30 and other times that are too high

Comment: @ez4nick Check out DateUtils API  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatElapsedTime(long) These methods are pretty nice and easy.

Answer (score 0):

you can adapt this example:

```
<string name="app_name">AndroidTimerExample</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="timerVal">00:00:00</string>
<string name="pauseButtonLabel">Pause</string>
<string name="startButtonLabel">Start</string>
 </resources>


  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.Handler;
  import android.os.SystemClock;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button startButton;
private Button pauseButton;

private TextView timerValue;

private long startTime = 0L;

private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);

    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

        }
    });

    pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
            customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);

        }
    });

}

private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
        timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a static class based mostly on [this link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-timer-example/) and partly on Answer from @Manolescu. I don't know if it's silly or good but it's worked for me in two apps:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class Timer extends Activity {
    public static Handler customHandler     = new Handler();
    public static long startTime           ;
    public static long timeInMilliseconds  ;
    public static long timeSwapBuff        ;
    public static long updatedTime         ;
    public static String timerValue        ;

    Timer(){
        initTimeParams();
    }
    public static void startTimer(){
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0) ;
    }
    public static void pauseTimer(){
        timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
        customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
    }
    public static void resetTimer(){
        initTimeParams();
        displayTimer();
        customHandler = new Handler();
        pauseTimer();
    }
    public static Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
            displayTimer();
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0) ;
        }
    };
    public static String displayTimer(){
        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000) ;
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000) ;
        timerValue = ("" + mins + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", secs) + "."
                + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        return timerValue;
    }
    public static void initTimeParams(){
        startTime = 0L ;
        timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
        timeSwapBuff = 0L;
        updatedTime = 0L;
        timerValue = "00:00.000";
    }
}
```

Here's how I used it in the (fairly lame) test app but it also did its job (total user time which excludes time spent showing 'Correct') in Deitel's Android Programming Flag app. (I.e., I started, paused, restarted, and eventually reset for next 'quiz' (running timer is not shown):

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        Button btnStart, btnPause, btnReset, btnShowTime;
        TextView time;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
            btnPause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
            btnReset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
            btnShowTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShowTime);
            time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
        public void start(View view) {
            Timer.startTimer();
        }
        public void pause(View view) {
            Timer.pauseTimer();
            showTime(view);
        }
        public void reset(View view) {
            Timer.resetTimer();
            showTime(view);
        }
        public void showTime(View view) {
            time.setText(Timer.displayTimer());
        }
    }
```

Here's xml:

`activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:onClick="start"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="152dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pause"
        android:id="@+id/btnPause"
        android:onClick="pause"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:id="@+id/btnReset"
        android:onClick="reset"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnPause"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show timer"
        android:id="@+id/btnShowTime"
        android:onClick="showTime"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnReset"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00:00.000"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:phoneNumber="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`strings.xml`

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">TimerTestWithTimerAsClass</string>

    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

`menu.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```